# spring batch probleme importing a csv file to database

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How to import CSV data to PostgreSQL Database using Spring Batch Job
Spring Batch is a powerful module to implement a batch process for tons of data conveniently.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of example on google or you can look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47471465/4253361

Answer (score 0):

To me, the best reference that helped me in a simple way to understand how spring batch works with examples is [tutorialspoint/spring-batch](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_batch/). Try this.